# Definição e função de QSharedPointer

Tags: c++, qt, ponteiro

Pelo que consegui entender, o QSharedPointer é um smart pointer, ou seja, um ponteiro que oferece coleta que lixo automática.

Se possível gostaria de um código que melhor explicasse isso, inclusive em que momento devo usa-lo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Depois de muito ler consegui entender. Mas é necessário saber o que é um QPointer.

Segundo a documentação do QT:

> A classe QPointer é uma classe modelo que fornece ponteiros **reservado** a QObject.
>   Um ponteiro guardado, QPointer , se comporta como um normal, C + + ponteiro T *, exceto que **ele é automaticamente ajustado para 0 quando o objeto referenciado é destruído** (ao contrário ponteiros normais C ++, que se tornam "ponteiros pendurados" em tais casos). T tem de ser uma **subclasse de QObject**.

Exemplo:

```
 QPointer<QLabel> label = new QLabel;
    label->setText("&Status:");
    ...
    if (label)
        label->show();
```

> Se o QLabel é excluído, entretanto, a variável label vai ficar com 0 em vez de um endereço inválido, e a última linha nunca será executado. 
>   As funções e os operadores disponíveis com um QPointer são os mesmos que estão disponíveis com um ponteiro normal, excepto os operadores aritméticos ponteiro (+, -, + + e -), que são normalmente utilizados apenas com matrizes de objetos.

Agora QSharedPointer:

> A classe QSharedPointer detém uma forte referência a um ponteiro compartilhado.
>   O QSharedPointer é um ponteiro automático, compartilhada em C + +. Ele se comporta exatamente como um ponteiro normal para fins normais, incluindo o respeito pela constness.
>   QSharedPointer excluirá o ponteiro está segurando quando ele sair do escopo, desde que não outros objetos QSharedPointer são referência a ele.
>   Um objeto QSharedPointer pode ser criado a partir de um ponteiro normal, outro objeto QSharedPointer ou mediante a promoção um objeto QWeakPointer a uma referência forte.

Obs.: O objetivo principal da **constness** é fornecer documentação e evitar erros de programação. Const permite deixar claro para si e aos outros de que algo não deve ser alterado.

Sabendo disso, podemos então levar em consideração esta postagem:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22304118/what-is-the-difference-between-qpointer-qsharedpointer-and-qweakpointer-classes

> QPointer só pode apontar para QObject casos. Ele será definido automaticamente para nullptr se o pontiagudo para objeto é destruído. É um ponteiro fraco especializada para QObject. Considere este fragmento:

```
QObject * obj = new QObject;
QPointer <QObject> pObj (obj); 
delete obj;
Q_ASSERT (pObj.isNull ()); //PObj será agora nullptr
```

> QSharedPointer Um ponteiro contados-referência. O objeto real só será excluído, quando todos os ponteiros compartilhados são destruídos.Equivalente a `std::shared_ptr.`

```
int * pi = new int; 
QSharedPointer <int> PI1 (pi); 
QSharedPointer <int> PI2 = pi1; 
pI1.clear (); //PI2 ainda está apontando para o pi, por isso não é eliminado 
pI2.clear (); // Não há ponteiros compartilhados mais, PI é eliminado.
```

> Note que enquanto há um ponteiro compartilhado, o objeto não será excluído!